# Unit Conversion Methods

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that converts certain units and I keep encountering errors. My program has 4 methods (one for the original unit, one to convert to the new unit, one for the conversion & one for how many units) as you can tell and each method is written correctly. When I ran it, I got the error of "unresolved compilation problem."

Here's the code:

```
public static String getUnitFrom(){
    String original = "";

    final String OZ = "oz";
    final String LB = "lb";
    final String IN = "in";
    final String FT = "ft";

    switch(original){
    case OZ:
        original = "oz";
        break;
    case LB:
        original = "lb";
        break;
    case IN:
        original = "in";
        break;
    case FT:
        original = "ft";
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    }
    return original;    

}

public static String getUnitTo(String conversionFromUnit){
    String conversionFromUnit = "";
    final String G = "g";
    final String KG = "kg";
    final String MM = "mm";
    final String CM = "cm";
    final String M = "m";

    if(getUnitFrom().equals("oz") || getUnitFrom().equals("lb")){
        switch(conversionFromUnit){
        case G:
            conversionFromUnit = "g";
            break;
        case KG:
            conversionFromUnit = "kg";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid conversion!");
        }
    }
    else if (getUnitFrom().equals("in") || getUnitFrom().equals("ft")){
        switch (conversionFromUnit){
        case MM:
            conversionFromUnit = "mm";
            break;
        case CM:
            conversionFromUnit = "cm";
            break;
        case M:
            conversionFromUnit = "m";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid conversion!");
        }
    }
    return conversionFromUnit;
}
public static double getValue(){
    double value = 0;

    if(getUnitFrom() > 0 && getUnitTo() > 0){
        value = input.nextDouble();
    }

}
public static double getConversionRate(String from, String to){
    double rate = 0;

    if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("oz")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("g"))){
        rate = 28.3;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("oz")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("kg"))){
        rate = 0.028;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("lb")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("g"))){
        rate = 453.6;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("lb")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("kg"))){
        rate = 0.045;
    }

    if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("in")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("mm"))){
        rate = 25.4;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("in")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("cm"))){
        rate = 2.54;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("in")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("m"))){
        rate = 0.0254;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("ft")) && to.equals(getUnitTo("mm"))){
        rate = 304.8;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("ft")) && to.equals(getUnitFrom("cm"))){
        rate = 30.48;
    }
    else if(from.equals(getUnitFrom("ft")) && to.equals(getUnitFrom("m"))){
        rate = 0.3048;
    }

    return rate;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String convertFrom = getUnitFrom();
    String convertTo = getUnitTo();
    double valueOf = getValue();
    System.out.println(getValue() + " " + getUnitFrom() + " = " + (getValue() * getConversionRate()) + " " + getUnitTo());

}
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is because your method getUnitTo(String) requires string as arguments whereas in your main method you aren't passing any.
2. if(getUnitFrom() > 0 && getUnitTo() > 0) : getUnitFrom returns a string which cannot be compared using ">" operator.
3. All the errors are because of incorrect function calls (check the signature of the function and pass the required values) .

Answer (score 0):

The issues are listed after the error is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method getUnitTo(String) in the type Testing is not applicable for the arguments ()
The method getConversionRate(String, String) in the type Testing is not applicable for the arguments ()
The method getUnitTo(String) in the type Testing is not applicable for the arguments ()

at testing.Testing.main(Testing.java:122)
```